# packaging options based on product flavor in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I m using packaging options to exclude some libs. Is it possible to have packaging options based on product flavor. For example -

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorDimensions 'models'
            S2 {
                flavorDimension 'models'
                minSdkVersion 22
                ....
            }
            S6 {
                flavorDimension 'models'
                minsdkversion 22
                ....
            }
        }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libs2.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libs6.so
    }
}
```

Now in above code, I want to exclude only `'lib/armeabi/libs2.so'` in apk generated for `s6` flavor and want to exclude only `'lib/arm64-v8a/libs6.so'` in apk generated for `s2` flavor

How can we achieve this.

Comment: For Kotlin DSL see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811835/8583692).

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered the same issue, and then, I developed a gradle plugin to resolve this. 
You can [check it(android-soexcluder) out here](https://github.com/Jween/android-soexcluder)

It is super easy to use:

```
soexcluder {
    s2 {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libs6.so'
    }

    s6 {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libs2.so'
    }
}
```

Beside this, there is even a sample project inside the [repository](https://github.com/Jween/android-soexcluder/tree/master/sample-android-app)

Comment: Would you happen to have something to exclude not just .so, but any files, for example from assets folder ? Will a line like 'exclude 'assets/file1.mp3' work?

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Dodolong solution:

```
  packagingOptions {
      ...
        gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->
            if (task.contains('assemble')) {
                if (task.contains('s2')) {
                    exclude 'lib/**/my_cool_lib1.so'
                } else if (task.contains('s6')) {
                    exclude 'lib/**/my_cool_lib2.so'
                }
            }
        }

  }
```

Comment: In my case it excluded library from all flavors. It probably would work if you build only specific flavor , but when you build all apks the final "exclude" list applied to all apks.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, I added the code phrases in dependencies closure. The concept is to detect flavor type when task being executed. And find instance of productFlavors to exclude libraries.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorDimensions 'models'
            S2 {
                flavorDimension 'models'
                minSdkVersion 22
                ....
            }
            S6 {
                flavorDimension 'models'
                minsdkversion 22
                ....
            }
        }
}

dependencies {
    gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->
        println 'task name is :' + task
        if (task.contains('assemble')) {
            def android = project.extensions.findByName("android")

            if(android != null) {
                com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions packagingOptions = android["packagingOptions"]

                if (packagingOptions != null) {
                    if(task.contains("S2")){
                        packagingOptions.exclude('lib/lib_for_s2.so')
                    } else if(task.contains("S6")) {
                        packagingOptions.exclude'lib/lib_for_s6.so')
                    }
                }
            }
            println 'libraries will be excluded: ' + packagingOptions.excludes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumble across the same issue but wanted to remove some assets files, running Android Studio 4.0.

It was actually super easy to exclude .so files per variant/flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'lib/x86/libshared.so'
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't work for assets!?

Comment: I tried it and the exclude applies to all flavors and not just one.

Comment: This does not work on Gradle 8.2.